# Error Thread 1: signal SIGBRT

Tags: objective-c, ios, sigabrt

I'm learning Objective C and I'm following examples from this book. However in some examples I keep getting this error! I followed the steps exactly, please help! I've already tried restoring the iOS simulator to its default settings and still no luck.

It's an app where you can record a sound and play it back. Here's the code...

```
- (IBAction)recordAudio:(id)sender {
    if ([self.recordButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Record Audio"]){
        [self.audioRecorder record];
        [self.recordButton setTitle:@"Stop Recording"
                           forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [self.audioRecorder stop];
        [self.recordButton setTitle:@"Record Audio"
                           forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        // Load the new sound in the audioplayer for playback
        NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory()
                             stringsByAppendingPaths:@"sound.caf"]];

        self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                            initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe in detail what is happening.  Does it crash when you start the app?  When you tap the button to start recording?  When you tap the button to stop recording?  Some other time?

Comment: When you get the error, the simulator will print out some info in the console, plus if you bring up the debugger it will show you the exception stack.  That will tell you where the error occurs.  With that information debugging this will probably be quite easy.  Without it, debugging is just a guessing game.

Answer (score 1):

I ran part of your code, and this was the error message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '***
-[__NSCFString stringsByAppendingPaths:]: paths argument is not an array'
```

As the documentation says, stringsByAppendingPaths returns an NSArray of NSString objects made by separately appending each NSString in an NSArray of paths to the receiver. @"sound.caf" is an NSString, not an NSArray, which raises the exception.

Change the following:

```
    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory()
                         stringsByAppendingPaths:@"sound.caf"]];
```

To:

```
    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory()
                         stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"]];
```

and it should work.